# Why would pthread_create() fail with only 2 threads active?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm having some trouble in my first foray into threads in C. I'm trying (for now) to write a very simple server program that accepts a socket connection and starts a new thread to process it. It seems to work fine except that it will only create about 300 threads (303, sometimes 304) before pthread_create() fails with the EAGAIN code, which means:

"The  system  lacked  the  necessary  resources to create another thread, or the system-imposed  limit  on  the  total  number  of threads in a process {PTHREAD_THREADS_MAX} would be exceeded."

This is *not* 303 threads at the same time - each thread exits which is confirmed by gdb. Each time the process request function is called there are two threads running.

So it means "the system lacked the necessary resources". My question is (and it may be a bit stupid) - what are these resources? Presumably it's a memory leak in my program (certainly possible, likely even), but I'd have thought that even so it could manage more than 300 considering the rest of the program does very little.

How can I find out how much memory my program has available to confirm that it's running out of it? There's plenty of memory and swap free so presumably there's an artificial limit imposed by the OS (Linux).

Thanks

Comment: can you post the code snippet that creates and destroys the threads?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are not creating the thread with the attribute [`PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/pthread_attr_setdetachstate.html) (or detaching them with [`pthread_detach()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/pthread_detach.html), you may need to call [`pthread_join()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/pthread_join.html) on each created thread after it exits to free up the resources associated with it.

Comment: Thankyou! Just set that attribute and it's gone well past 4000 threads and counting. Many thanks - that's about 3 hours of frustration fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a little overkill(?) but [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) can help you locate memleaks in Linux.

Could you perhaps post some code snippets? Preferably the parts where you allocate/free memory/sockets and where you create your threads.